# Oracle SQL Developer limit number of character of datatype char(5)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sqldatatypes, check-constraints

I was tasked to implement a table with a variable groupcode. There are several requirements.

1. char(5)
2. 2 or 4 uppercase letters plus 1 digit whose value is between 1 and 4 (e.g., AA1, AABB1)
3. Any input other violating point 1 and 2 should be banned

The only thing I can come up with is regexp_like but my efforts are in vain, for example

```
create table Test(
groupcode char(5) check(
regexp_like(groupcode, '^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$', 'c') 
)
);

INSERT INTO Test(groupcode) VALUES ('AA1');
```

I inserted this but it keep telling me there's some violation, in which I don't understand.

I specify `^` and `$` because I don't want something like `'bbAA1'` or `'AA1bb'` appear.

I am also open to non-regex solution. After all the work in this afternoon, I am starting to doubt my approach.

**Edit**--To Tim:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$` only allows (exactly) three characters. But a column defined as `char(5)` gets padded with spaces if you provide less than three, so in reality `'AA1'` will be stored as `'AA1  '` which violates your regex.

Use `char(3)` instead.

Better yet, never use `char` at all (you just experienced one of the reasons why), use `varchar(5)` or `varchar(3)` both will work with your regex.

---

> 2 or 4 uppercase letters plus 1 digit whose value is between 1 and 4

That's not what your regex does. `[A-Z]{2}` is **exactly** two uppercase letters. If you want to allow patterns of different lengths there is no way you can use `char(5)` unless you also include the spaces in the regex:

```
create table test
(
  groupcode char(5) check(
      regexp_like(groupcode, '(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]  $)|(^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]$)', 'c'))
);
```

The above regex allows two uppercase characters followed by on digit and two spaces *or* four uppercase characters followed by one digit.

Comment: Good news: I am so grateful that I understand the concept of `'AA1   '`; Bad news: I need to follow strictly the char(5 constraint. :(.

Comment: @AndesLam: the part "2 uppercase letters plus 1 digit" can't be satisfied with a regex on a `char(5)` column. You **really** should be using `varchar(5)` instead. There is absolutely no advantage whatsoever (neither in performance nor in storage space) when using `char(5)` - only disadvantages.

Comment: Was any reason given for the `char(5)`? It's not only wrong here, `char` is always wrong. I have never seen a good use for it as a column datatype. There's an argument that it documents the intention that the value will always have a certain length, but I've never found that convincing - if the length is so important, add a check constraint. Perhaps the person demanding this is thinking of some other RDBMS where it works differently.

Comment: I don't see how CHAR(3) or VARCHAR(3) could accommodate the longer codes (in the same column). Separately: the regexp can be simplified to `^([A-Z]{2}){1,2}[1-4]$`. Note `[1-4]` at the end - the OP used `[0-9]` but the requirements he gave say "between 1 and 4".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    groupcode VARCHAR(5),
    CONSTRAINT (CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(groupcode, '^[A-Z]{2}([A-Z]{2})?[1-4]$', 'c')))
);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^                from the start of the column
    [A-Z]{2}     match AA, AB, BB, etc.
    ([A-Z]{2})?  then match another optional AA, AB, BB, etc.
    [1-4]        match 1-4
$                end of the column
```

### Demo

Late Edit: The @Horse answer correctly points out that you should use `VARCHAR` here.  But your regex also had a problem, which I fixed.

Comment: @AndesLam I botched the check constraint syntax (but also was assuming you had that right).  Try listing the check constraint as a formal constraint in the create table statement.  My answer seems to be working, at least in a demo.

Comment: Is formal constraint mean `constraint test_c check(regexp_like(groupcode, '^[A-Z]{2}([A-Z]{2})?[1-4]$', 'c'))`? Because in this case, Oracle SQL Developer still doesn't budge. But I understand the logic. :((